# JsonConvert.DeserializeObject returns null only with Xamarin apps

Tags: c#, xamarin, asp.net-web-api, json.net

I have a web-Api method that validates the user's entry and returns `BadRequest(ModelState)` on any validation error. So far everything is good

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Register(RegisterModel model)
{
      if (!ModelState.IsValid)
      {
           return BadRequest(ModelState);
      }
      ...
}
```

Now, In my Xamarin application I wanted to return the returned `json` to an `Object`. I tried to use `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject`, it returns null!?

I built a sample app on [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ocA05b) , it works fine.

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var content = "{\"Message\":\"The request is invalid.\",\"ModelState\":{\"UserName\":[\"user name is required\"],\"Password\":[\"password is required\"]}}";

        var details = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ModelStateErrorModel>(content);

        foreach(var detail in details.ModelState)
            Console.WriteLine("Key [{0}] and Message [{1}]",detail.Key,detail.Value[0]);
    }
}

public class ModelStateErrorModel
{
    public string Message{get;set;}
    public Dictionary<string,string[]> ModelState{get;set;}
}
```

My Xamarin Settings are

- Newtonsoft.Json 10.0.3
- Xamarin.Forms 2.5.0.121934
- Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps 2.2.1

The code I am using in Xamarin as follows

```
 if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)
 {
      var details = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ModelStateErrorModel>(content);
      return details; // here the value of details is always null
 }
```

I am not able to figure out why the deserialize is returning null, any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: Did you verify that the object passed in deserialize method is not null or empty?

Comment: Show the code which is not working and the json you're trying to deserialize please.

Comment: Not sure if it will make a difference... but are you using `Xamarin.Forms` `.netstandard` or `.netframework`?

Comment: @NevilleNazerane it is `.NET Standard 2.0`

Comment: @RawitasKrungkaew the object returned the errors which I used in the sample above `content`.

Comment: @Set I tested it with the content you provided in your example and it works. Can you provide an example **with a json which returns null**?

Comment: @DennisSchröer the content I included in the question, is returning null inside the Xamarin app while it returns value when I tested it on dotnetfiddle and I included the part when it is returning null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `async` method. Your code might be returning null because you didn't wait till the method `Deserialize` to finish.

Can you confirm if this is your case?

1. Use `Task.Run`
2. Use `Wait();` at the end

**Example**

```
ModelStateErrorModel details = null;
Task.Run(()=>{
     if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)
     {
          details = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ModelStateErrorModel>(content);
     }
}).Wait();
return details;
```

Hope this will help you

Answer (score 1):

Try Something like this...

```
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ObjectOfTheClassToBeSerialized);

var content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
HttpResponseMessage response = null;

response = await client.PostAsync(LinkToTheWebService, content);
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode){
     var item = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
     var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TypeOfTheClassToBeDeSerialized>(item);
}
```

Comment: thank you for the reply...if you read the question, you would save time writing this answer. the response is returning `badrequest` and the content `item` in your code, is of type `ModelState` and sample of the returned response is mentioned in the question already... the problem is that I am trying to deserialize the returned string to ModelState Dictionary `Dictionary<string,string[]>` , and the result is null